# Office Web App 2013 configuration error

Tags: configuration, office-web-apps, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a binding between SP2013 server and Office Web App 2013 server using the below PS Script:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "OWAServerName"
```

But I get the below error:

```
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 1 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 2 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 3 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 4 of 5).
WARNING: The server did not respond. Trying again (attempt 5 of 5).
New-SPWOPIBinding : Sorry, we have encountered an error and New-SPWOPIBinding
has failed. If you are using a server configured with HTTP, you must include
the -AllowHTTP parameter.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName OWAServerName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Share...tNewWOPIBinding
   :SPCmdletNewWOPIBinding) [New-SPWOPIBinding], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWOPIB
   Inding
```

EventViewer displays the below error:

> An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:
>   Subject Name: CN=, OU=, O=, L=, S=, C=
>   Issuer Name: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US Thumbprint:
>
> Errors:
>
> SSL policy errors have been encountered.  Error code '0x2'.

I have uploaded the SSL Binding certificate for the https external URL to Office Web App server and also to the SharePoint 2013 server.

`https://ExternalURL/hosting/Discovery/` displays the XML file.

I checked with my network team and they confirmed that they are no firewall restriction between SharePoint server and OWA server.

Can someone help me fix the issue and proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Oops:The below PS Script worked for me.

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "ExternalURL"
```

ExternalURL - is the external URL used while configuring Office Web App Server.

In all the Microsoft articles,it was mentioned to use the InternalURL/OWA FQDN.Using External URL will cause any problem?

Comment: (e.g) New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "test-owa.contoso.com"